# Svelte giving warning for additional class selector on :global()

Tags: sass, svelte, sveltekit

I am using SCSS in my sveltekit +layout.svelte file to create a global stylesheet. I couldn't find a built-in way to make a global stylesheet so I resorted to just using :global(). This is the code I used:

```scss
:global(:where(p, .content)) {
    $size: 1rem;

    &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-block-end: #{$line-height}rem;
    }

    &.dropcap::first-letter {
        $line-count: 2;
        font-size: calc($size * (1 + ($line-count * $line-height)));
        float: left;
        line-height: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

(note: `:where()` is used because `:global()` doesn't support multiple selectors)

The first rule of `&:not` works fine, but the second rule of `&.dropcap` shows a warning in the terminal of unused selector (the only content that will match it would go in the `<slot />` of layout) and it gets removed from the css output. When I use `&:global(.dropcap)` svelte also includes the second `:global()` in the css output. How do I make svelte not remove the css?

Comment: As far as I know, you can write directly `:global(p, .content)` .

Comment: @RiadhAdrani Nope, didn't work. My svelte version is 3.54.0 and sveltekit is 1.5.6

Comment: You are right, it works with `h1, h2, h3, h4` but not with classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:global()` might not propagate inward, you may have to add it everywhere.

For global stylesheets it usually is easier to import them in the `<script>` along the lines of:

```js
import '../styles/sheet.scss';
```

This requires the build to be set up to handle such imports, SvelteKit uses Vite which should be able to do this by default.

Comment: Glad it helped. If this sufficiently answered the question, you can accept it using the check mark outline to its side.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, wrapping the problematic selector with `:where` made the warning goes away (and works).

```css
:global(:where(p, .content)) {
    $size: 1rem;

    &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-block-end: #{$line-height}rem;
    }

    &:where(.dropcap::first-letter) {
        $line-count: 2;
        font-size: calc($size * (1 + ($line-count * $line-height)));
        float: left;
        line-height: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```